# Localhost 404 Not Found XAMPP server

Tags: php, xampp, webserver, localhost

Good Day Everyone!

I am having problems with XAMPP in particular, I suppose that typing "localhost" alone in the browser should bring up something, but that does not been the case for me. I did typed in localhost:8080 and it works as it shows the xampp site. However, when I try to get into another folder let's say htdocs, I wrote it like this "localhost:8080/xampp/htdocs, it does not let me and it shows that object not found. Can someone please help me with this problem? I tried stopping and starting the server and restarting my computer but to no avail. I did ensure that the folder was there. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I have been where you at.
By default the root folder for the webserver is `htdocs`, so this means if you have a folder called test inside the htdocs folder, you would need to use this URL `localhost:8080/test` to access the content in the test folder.

I recommend you to change the document root in the config file `httpd.conf` to another directory or another drive. For example to change the root directory to C: then you would need to change these two lines in the `httpd.conf`

```
DocumentRoot "C:/"
<Directory "C:/">
```

Comment: I did the localhost:8080/test and it still showed the object not found error. I still have the same problem when I changed the directory root as you suggested, my listen is at 8080 right now. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: Did you create the test folder?

Comment: Can you create the test folder in the directory you set on the confi file , called test and then try again.